# How to exclude a certain file type using newsmangler

Tags: command-line, python

I'm trying to upload everything in a folder besides a .avi file and i was wondering what i would put at the end of the path for it to ignore all avi files.

I know that putting "/*avi" will make it upload only the avi, but i'm trying to make it upload everything besides the avi.

So can someone give me some pointers as i'm still fairly new the ubuntu world.

Here is the command i'm using

python poster.py -f "[test]" -c sample.conf -g alt.binaries.test /killer/Desktop/Downloads/the\folder\i\wanna\upload/*

I'm just trying to figure what i'd have to do to upload that whole folder, but not upload the avi files inside it. I would just move the avi files out, but i plan on doing stuff like this a lot so i don't wanna have to keep moving the files and would rather just know how to exclude them.

Comment: Does no one know a simple solution to this?

Comment: Upload to where? Using which tool?

Comment: Using newsmangler https://github.com/madcowfred/newsmangler

Comment: Please update your question to make it reflect that you you want to upload with a particular tool.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash, you can use the pattern

```
/path/to/files/!(*.avi)
```

to represent all files other than AVI files.

Comment: I really thought this was going to work, but it tells me that "event not found"

Comment: You have shell history turned on, so you should escape your esclamation mark: `/path/to/files/\!(*.avi)`
`

Comment: It requires that the extglob shell option has been enabled. Put the line `shopt -s extglob` at the start of the script where you need it, and put it in `~/.bashrc` to have it enabled in interactive sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I did not know the answer to this, but after a little digging up I found a good answer for you:

```
rsync /source/folder -av --exclude='*.avi' /destination/folder
```

You can add as many excludes as you like: --exclude='*.avi' --exclude='*.mkv' --exclude='*.mp3' ect..

The -v option is for verbose, so that you see in the output what's being synced.

Comment: So, would just adding --exclude='*.avi' to the end of each python command make it ignore the avi files?

Comment: I don't know python and exactly what you want to upload. I offered you a solution to sync 2 directories excluding certain file types

Comment: No, "--exclude" is not a generic python parameter, it's a parameter for the "rsync" utility.